# Asymptotic behavior of $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{k^2}{x^2} }$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}\sqrt{ 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} } &; x>1 \\ 0  &; x\leq 1 \\ \end{array}\right.$$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right).$$
What's the asymptotic behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: The sum is not well-defined (at $k>x$ it becomes complex). If we consider $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{[x]} \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{k^2}{x^2} }\,; g(x)\to\infty$ at $x\to\infty$

Comment: Wouldn’t the sum diverge as the test to divergence limit diverges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$\begin{align}
& g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1 - \frac{k^2}{x^2}} &;\; x > k \\
0 &;\; x \le k .
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

Note that $ g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) $ decreases with $ k $: for any fixed $ x $, $ g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \ge g\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right) $ for all $ k $. On the other hand, $ g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) $ increases with $ x $, i.e., $ x_2 > x_1 \implies g\left(\frac{x_2}{k}\right) \ge g\left(\frac{x_1}{k}\right) $.

Let $ \lceil x \rceil $ denote the smallest integer greater than or equal to $ x $. Then,

$\begin{align}
& f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil x \rceil - 1} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) + \sum_{k = \lceil x \rceil}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil x \rceil - 1} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) + 0 .
\end{align}$

Given any $ M \ge 3 $, let $ 2 M_0 + 1 $ be the largest odd number less than or equal to $ M $. For any $ x \ge 2 M_0 + 1 $,

$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^{\lceil x \rceil - 1} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^{2 M_0} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \\
&> \sum_{k=1}^{M_0} g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) &&\left( \text{because } g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) > 0 \text{ for } x > k \right) \\
&\ge M_0 \sqrt{1 - \frac{M_0^2}{x^2}} &&\left( \text{because } g\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \ge g\left(\frac{x}{M_0}\right) \text{ for } k \le M_0 \right) \\
&> M_0 \sqrt{1 - \frac{M_0^2}{(2 M_0)^2}} &&\left( \text{because } x > 2 M_0 \right) \\
&= M_0 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} .
\end{align}$

Given any large $ K $, one can choose $ M $ such that $ M_0 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} > K $. Then, for all $ x \ge 2 M_0 + 1 $, $ f(x) > K $. Hence, $ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty $.

Comment: It'd be great to know at what speed $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$? It seems like $f(x) \sim O(x)$ as $x\to\infty$. What's the most accurate that we can say? For instance, for a,b given, $f(x)-ax+b \sim O(?)$

Comment: From the proof, it can be seen that for large $ x $, $ f(x) > \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} (x - 1) $. On the other hand, it is easy to show that for any $ x \ge 2 $, $ f(x) \le x $. So, yes $ f(x) = O(x) $ as $ x \to \infty $.

Comment: please see the follow up at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412519/asymptotic-behavior-of-fx-sum-k-1-infty-sqrt-max-1-frack2x